# How to accept doc file input with html and send as attachment with mailgun, in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, mailgun

I'm trying to accept doc files with html and then send the uploaded file to an email using mailgun. I was able to upload the file but once it's uploaded, I don't know how to manipulate or use it. I printed out the uploaded file and all I could see was the file size, name and some other parameters but not the file content itself. My main goal is to accept the file and send the file and its content to a specific input. Here's what I currently have
View:

```
<form method="post" action="send_resume" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name"><label>Email</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <label>Resumé/CV</label>
    <input name="resume" type="file" accept=".doc, .docx"><br>
    <button type="">Send</button>
</form>
```

Controller function:

```
public function send_resume()
{
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: After file is uploaded you should have path to the file already. You can use that path for attach file to the mail. In other hand, if you want content of file itself, you can use PHP's `file_get_contents()` or CodeIgniter's `file_helper` using that path.

Comment: Oh youre right, I can attach from the path. thanks for pointing this out. @Tpojka

Comment: Glad I clould help.